# TCP: почему при отключении кабеля образуется «черная дыра», то есть какое-то время Write теряет данные, но ошибку не выдает?

Tags: сокет, сеть, клиент-сервер, tcp-ip

Создаю сервер. В интернете, не в локалке.
Подключение персистентное.

Вот у клиента в сетевом кабеле пропадает контакт.
И как раз в это время клиент собирается отправить сообщение.
Клиент вызывает **Write** и... всё! Тишина!
**Write** успешно отрабатывает, никаких экскепшн, но данные теряются, они не отправляются даже если сразу же воткнуть кабель на место. Еще раз: данные - теряются, безвозвратно.
И более того, я опять вызываю **Write**, и опять то же самое!

Однако, если после вынимания кабеля выждать с пол-минуты и только потом вызывать **Write**, то экспешн будет.

Почему не сразу?
Почему теряются данные и (оказывается) даже есть термин "black hole", хотя все вокруг трубят о надежности TCP?

Я не знаю, что делать и как правильно.

Я бы мог после этого **Write** сразу вызывать **Read**, вот он вроде работает как следует, но дело в том, что по условию задачи *я должен на клиенте в фоновом потоке постоянно крутить этот **Read**в цикле в режиме ожидания*, *и на сервере тоже цикл*, поэтому я не могу использовать **Read** в других местах - это запутает код, ну если только с Peek, но правильное ли это решение?

Говорят, что для корректной работы поможет heartbeat/keepalive, но я не понимаю каким образом, как не понимаю и суть проблемы. Ну не должен **Write** терять данные.

P.S. Описанное явление очень странно. Ведь сервер в ответ всегда отправляет пакет с флагом ACK, а если нет кабеля, то этот пакет не придет, так почему же ОС клиента не проверяет пришел ли он, и не выбрасывает экскепшн?
И почему она начинает его выбрасывать при более длительном обрыве кабеля (примерно пол-минуты)?

P.P.S. 
ОС - Windows 8.1 x64 клиент, Windows 2000 x64 сервер.
Язык сервера - C#.
Язык клиента - C# либо Delphi 7 (Indy 9), в обоих языках одинаково.

Comment: Почитайте https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/316128/ это просто родные глюки TCP IP, в теории он вроде как должен обеспечивать надежность передачи данных, на практике есть много всяких исключений.

Comment: Не для протокола, чисто предположение. Приложение не в кабель суёт байты, а отправляет их в соотв. системный сервис. А там цепь длинная - IP-стек, драйвер сетевой карты, антивирус, прости господи... и каждый при проблемах может надеяться, что всё вылечится. и ему удастся пропихнуть твои байты куда просишь... и у каждого своё время, после которого он понимает, что не склалось... а обратно отдать некуда и некому - значит, в корзину. Вот тебе и потери...

Comment: Странно что после возвращения кабеля, данные не передаются. Всегда считал что эта ситуация (с временным пропаданием кабеля), будет обрабатываться как и потеря пакета. Тоесть он будет переслан через несколько секунд если клиент не подтвердит получение.

Comment: @Arnial Ну, я могу еще раз попробовать создать сервер и клиент и снова убедиться, что пакет теряется. Могу сделать это на разных языках, в них же немного разные обертки. Сейчас я копаю Java и Clojure, для последнего есть библиотека, которая по словам автора работает очень стабильно.

Comment: @rdorn Там нет решений, там только описания и демонстрация проблем, причем демонстрация с помощью каких-то утилит UNIXового стека, значит мне еще и их надо осваивать, и когда мне все это успеть, лучше Clojure покопаю, для него хотя бы есть какая-то библиотека, которая по заявлениям автора работает полностью стабильно, еще есть в конце-концов всякие Skype, ICQ и прочие, которые ведут себя адекватно, хотелось бы найти самый простой клиент который однако ведет адекватно, и дебажить/копать код, опять же это время...

Comment: @KG "там нет решений" - там есть ответ на почему оно себя так ведет.   А если почитаете внимательно, поймете что это проблема не конкретного клиента, клиент может быть абсолютно стабильным, сетевого стека.

Comment: @rdom где там этот ответ и что делать?